# Symfony2 didn't show error message after form login submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Why symfony didn't show message error when i failed to submit login form?

my security config:

```
security:
    firewalls:
      secure_area:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
          login_path: bunga_core_user_login
          check_path: bunga_core_user_check
          use_forward: false
          username_parameter: _username
          password_parameter: _password
          post_only: true
          use_referer: true
        logout:
          path: bunga_core_user_logout
          target: bunga_core
        anonymous: ~

    access_control:
      - { path: ^/user/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/user/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
      - { path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }

    role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]

    providers:
      main:
        entity:
          class: BungaCoreBundle:User
          property: username

    encoders:
      Bunga\CoreBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:  sha1
        iterations: 1
        encode_as_base64: false
```

UserController

```
<?php

namespace Bunga\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get login error if any
        if($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return array(
            'lastUsername' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error' => $error
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function adminAction() {
        return array();
    }
}
```

my entity: User

```
<?php

namespace Bunga\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bunga\CoreBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return Role[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array($this->getRole());
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the password used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * This should be the encoded password. On authentication, a plain-text
     * password will be salted, encoded, and then compared to this value.
     *
     * @return string The password
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Twig template for UserController:login

```
{% block body %}
    <h1 class="text-center">Login Form</h1>
    {% if error %}
        <div class="error">{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('bunga_core_user_check') }}" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="control-label col-xs-2">User</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ lastUsername }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="password" name="_password" />
            </div>
        </div>

        {#
            If you want to control the URL the user
            is redirected to on success (more details below)
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
        #}

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">login</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```